# OpenSSL windows execute with space path not working golang

Tags: go, openssl

I have a space path from Windows `001  .video.mp4.enc`, but `exec.Command` not working when remove space `001.video.mp4.enc` it's work,

```
    cmdPromp := "cmd.exe"
    command := "openssl smime -decrypt -in C:\dataencrypt\001  .video.mp4.enc -inform DER -inkey key/key.private -out datadecrypt/001  .video.mp4 -binary"
    arg := []string{"/c", command}
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdPromp, arg...)
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either rename the files, or use quotation marks around the file names.

```
command := `openssl smime -decrypt -in C:\dataencrypt\001 " .video.mp4.enc" -inform DER -inkey key/key.private -out datadecrypt/001 " .video.mp4" -binary`
```

Incidentally, it is probably best to use backtick quotes `` rather as than double quotes "" here as I have done, because Windows paths can look a lot to like backslashes that should be interpreted, e.g. \n is a new line, while backtick is the raw characters https://go101.org/article/basic-types-and-value-literals.html#string-literals